# Wordpress header image not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

I added a function in my functions.php file called add_theme_support('custom-header');

After going to Appearance -> Custom Header, and uploading my file, it refuses to display on my website. If I check my Wordpress admin panel, the image is there clear as day on the UI but will not display on my site, any reasons why?

Header.php code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Wordpress Theme</title>
    <?php wp_head();?>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
<body <?php body_class();?>

      <img alt="" src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your css that you don't have a "display: none / hidden" on the class or id of the header image?

You can double check that by inspecting element.